# How to filter agenda headings not just by date but also time of day

Tags: org-mode

If I `(setq org-agenda-todo-ignore-scheduled 'future)`, then my agenda view will now show tasks that are scheduled for tomorrow or later. But this setting does not appear to take the time of day into account.

If now is `<2018-02-15 Thu 12:00>`, it makes no difference if I annotate a task with `SCHEDULED: <2018-02-15 Thu 05:00>` or `SCHEDULED: <2018-02-15 Thu 17:00>`. Both will show up in the agenda.

This is a pity, because sometimes I want to snooze a task for an hour or two. But the minimal resolution of Org mode agenda views appears to be one day.

Is there a way to tell Org mode to take time of day into account when filtering agenda tasks?

Answer (score 1):

Insert the following into your configuration.

```
(setq org-agenda-todo-ignore-time-comparison-use-seconds t)
```

From the variable documentation:

```
org-agenda-todo-ignore-time-comparison-use-seconds is a variable defined in ‘org-agenda.el’.

Documentation:
Time unit to use when possibly ignoring an agenda item.

See the docstring of various ‘org-agenda-todo-ignore-*’ options.
The default is to compare time stamps using days.  An item is thus
considered to be in the future if it is at least one day after today.
Non-nil means to compare time stamps using seconds.  An item is then
considered future if it has a time value later than current time.
```